# usage of findContours causes ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, opencv, contour, motion-detection

I am working with RaspberryPi 3
I am trying to run [This](https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Tracking-Turret/blob/master/turret.py) code
which shows below error

```
Waiting for video to adjust... Done. 
 Waiting for motion. 
Waiting for video to adjust... Done. 
 Waiting for motion.  
Traceback (most recent call last): 
        File "/home/pi/Tracking-Turret/turret.py", line 418, in <module> t.motion_detection(show_video=True) 
        File "/home/pi/Tracking-Turret/turret.py", line 273, in motion_detection VideoUtils.find_motion(self.__move_axis, show_video=show_video) 
        File "/home/pi/Tracking-Turret/turret.py", line 134, in find_motion c = VideoUtils.get_best_contour(thresh.copy(), 5000) 
        File "/home/pi/Tracking-Turret/turret.py", line 158, in get_best_contour im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgmask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
        ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: I think, the return of `cv2.findContours` function is a tuple with 2 values like `(a, b)`. but your code expect 3 values `(im, contours, hierarchy)`. so you need check, what you want to get.

Comment: Not true.  It has never returned (x,y) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version change.  Prior to OpenCV 4.4, `findCounters` did return three things.  Newer versions return 2: `contours` and `hierarchy`.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

Comment: question is a duplicate. if you have new insights (behavior depending on version), add it to the other question.